# How to execute only one task at a time in celery worker, without losing it and maintaining the order of tasks in queue

Tags: python, redis, celery

I want to certain task to be run only one at a time. Other types of tasks can be run in concurrent worker.

I can't use celery's [example](http://celery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/task-cookbook.html#ensuring-a-task-is-only-executed-one-at-a-time), as I'll lose the new task if one is already running.

I can retry the task again after some time but if a new task(third one) comes in meanwhile and if first one is already finished then it'll be run(and second one will be still waiting) which I don't want. I want to keep the order.

I know the simplest thing would be to have two workers and two queue. One worker with >1 concurrency which watches queue of other tasks and one with only 1 concurrency and it will watch the queue of only `one_at_a_time` type tasks. But I want to use only one worker with >1 concurrency.

I have an approach by storing a queue directly in `redis`:

```
@app.task()
def one_at_a_time_task(arg):
  if redis.queue.length == 0:
    redis.queue.add(arg)
    call_my_task()
  else:
    redis.queue.add(arg)

def call_my_task():
  while(redis.queue.length > 0):
    taskArgs = redis.queue.first
    # actual task logic ...

    redis.queue.dequeue
```

I'll have to put lock on queue so that race condition doesn't happen, but it's doable(I think).

Is there any better/simpler way this could be done? Maybe where i don't need to maintain queue and can use directly celery's queue?

Answer (score 1):

### i re-read your problem description and it says "one task at a time" and so my idea 2 would not work. **so should use a simple for loop or "idea 1" (one celery worker with concurrency set to 1).**

---

#### idea 0: don't use celery. just do a for loop to process each task.

#### idea 1: one Celery worker with concurrency set to 1

- strictly speaking if you want to process one task at a time and maintain the order of the tasks.
- you COULD start one worker. then set concurrency to 1.
- this one worker would then process one task at a time and maintain the order of the tasks.
- but this would not offer any advantages and instead would just introduce more complexity compared to just having a for loop to process all the tasks without celery or a celery worker.

#### idea 2: N workers with concurrency set to M

- one way to achieve faster processing would be to do something similar to  python's `multiprocess.pool.Pool` (or `multiprocess.pool.ThreadPool`) which has a function that does what you want called `map`, or `starmap`.
- to achieve this using Celery

  - you would spin up N workers with M concurrency
  - then you could have a for loop to submit all the tasks
  - append each AsyncResult in a list
  - then have a second for loop to wait on each AsyncResult in the same order
- this would achieve NxM parallel processing using Celery and still ensure your results are in the same order
- also if my proposed design sounds too difficult to implement you can use the Celery built in `map`, `starmap`, `chunks` which already implement for you what i proposed: see Celery docs https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#map-starmap